# Fancyheader header not working

Tags: fancyhdr

I am trying to use `fancyhdr` but it doesn't work (no error, but the header is not displayed), maybe because of the template I am using `thesiskiv`

```
\documentclass[czech,BP]{thesiskiv}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\declarationmale

\title{Využítí neuronových sítí\\ v sémantice slov}

\abstracttexten{The text of the abstract (in English). It contains the English translation of the thesis title and a short description of the thesis.}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
  unicode=true,
  linkcolor=black,
  citecolor=black,
  urlcolor=black,
  bookmarksopen=true}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
%
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Úvod}
V souboru \texttt{literatura.bib} jsou uvedeny příklady, jak citovat knihu \cite{KnuthAOCP2}, článek v časopisu \cite{Hoare1961}, webovou stránku \cite{Graphics2D}.

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\bibliographystyle{csplainnatkiv}
{\raggedright\small
\bibliography{literatura.bib}{}
}

\end{document}
```

Here is the `thesiskiv` template

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{thesiskiv}[2016/03/14 Thesis at DCSE (KIV)]
\DeclareOption{czech}{\def\KIV@lng{czech}}
\DeclareOption{english}{\def\KIV@lng{british}}
\DeclareOption{BP}{}
\DeclareOption{DP}{}
\ExecuteOptions{czech}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage[czech,british]{babel}
\expandafter\AtBeginDocument%
 \expandafter{%
 \expandafter\selectlanguage%
 \expandafter{\KIV@lng}}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,left=37mm,right=37mm,top=33mm,bottom=40mm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.1}
\ifx\uv\undefined
 \newcommand{\uv}[1]{\quotedblbase{#1}\textquotedblleft}
\fi 
%
\newcommand{\university}[1]{\def\@university{#1}}
\newcommand{\faculty}[1]{\def\@faculty{#1}}
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\def\@department{#1}}
\newcommand{\subject}[1]{\def\@subject{#1}}
\newcommand{\titlepageyear}[1]{\def\KIV@titlepageyear{#1}}
\newcommand{\titlepagetown}[1]{\def\KIV@titlepagetown{#1}}
\newcommand{\declarationtown}[1]{\def\KIV@declarationtown{#1}}
\newcommand{\declarationdate}[1]{\def\KIV@declarationdate{#1}}
\newcommand{\abstracttexten}[1]{\long\def\KIV@abstracttexten{#1}}
\newcommand{\abstracttextcz}[1]{\long\def\KIV@abstracttextcz{#1}}
\newif\ifdeclarationfemale
\newcommand{\declarationfemale}{\declarationfemaletrue}
\newcommand{\declarationmale}{\declarationfemalefalse}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \Huge\bfseries
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \hangindent=1.5em
        \noindent\hbox to 1.5em{\thechapter\hfil}%
    \fi%
    #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\def\KIV@chapstarrule{\vrule width0pt height 120pt}
%
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  {% first page is a bit bigger
  \enlargethispage{25mm}
  \addtolength{\topmargin}{-8mm}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}%
  \begin{center}%
    {\fontsize{22}{28}\selectfont
     \@university\par
     \@faculty\par
     \hbox to \textwidth{\hss\@department\hss}}\vskip 26mm
    {\fontsize{28}{35}\selectfont\bf
     \@subject\par\vskip 17mm
     \@title\par}\vfill
    {\fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont\KIV@titlepagetown\ \KIV@titlepageyear
     \hfill\@author}
  \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}%
  }
  \setcounter{page}{2}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \hbox{}\vfill
  {\centering\Huge\bfseries Místo této strany bude\\ zadání práce.\par}
  \vfill\vfill

  \chapter*{\KIV@chapstarrule\KIV@declarationname}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \KIV@declarationtext\par
  \vskip 1.5em
  \noindent\KIV@declarationfoot\KIV@declarationdate\par
  \vskip 0.7em
  \noindent\hfill\@author\hspace*{10mm}\par
  \newpage

  \pagestyle{empty}
  {%
  \begin{otherlanguage}{british}
  \section*{\KIV@chapstarrule Abstract}
  \medskip
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\parindent 1.5em\noindent \KIV@abstracttexten}
  \end{otherlanguage}
  \vspace{-5em} % active only if both abstracts fit on a single page
  \begin{otherlanguage}{czech}
  \section*{\KIV@chapstarrule Abstrakt}
  \medskip
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\parindent 1.5em\noindent \KIV@abstracttextcz}
  \end{otherlanguage}
  }%
  \newpage

  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \pagestyle{plain}
}

\@ifclasswith{thesiskiv}{czech}{
 \university{Západočeská univerzita v Plzni}
 \faculty{Fakulta aplikovaných věd}
 \department{Katedra informatiky a výpočetní techniky}
 \@ifclasswith{thesiskiv}{BP}
  {\subject{Bakalářská práce}\def\KIV@thesistype{bakalářskou}}{}
 \@ifclasswith{thesiskiv}{DP}
  {\subject{Diplomová práce}\def\KIV@thesistype{diplomovou}}{}
 \titlepagetown{Plzeň}
 \declarationtown{Plzni}
 \def\KIV@declarationname{Prohlášení}
 \def\KIV@declarationtext{Prohlašuji, že jsem \KIV@thesistype\ práci vypracoval\ifdeclarationfemale{a}\fi\ samostatně a výhradně s~použitím citovaných pramenů.}
 \def\KIV@declarationfoot{V \KIV@declarationtown\ dne\ }
}{}
\@ifclasswith{thesiskiv}{english}{
 \university{University of West Bohemia}
 \faculty{Faculty of Applied Sciences}
 \department{Department of Computer Science and Engineering}
 \@ifclasswith{thesiskiv}{BP}
   {\subject{Bachelor's thesis}\def\KIV@thesistype{bachelor's}}{}
 \@ifclasswith{thesiskiv}{DP}
  {\subject{Master's thesis}\def\KIV@thesistype{master's}}{}
 \titlepagetown{Plzeň}
 \declarationtown{Plzeň}
 \def\KIV@declarationname{Declaration}
 \def\KIV@declarationtext{I hereby declare that this \KIV@thesistype\ thesis is completely my own work and that I used only the cited sources.}
 \def\KIV@declarationfoot{\KIV@declarationtown,\ }
}{}

\titlepageyear{\number\year}
\declarationdate{\today}
\declarationmale
```

Comment: Ok, I found it, it was in the template               \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \pagestyle{plain}, changed it to fancy at it works now

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was resolved in comments and was caused by a line in a custom class not generally available. (The class is in the question, but the specific issue is unlikely to be of more general interest and the generic issue is already addressed in numerous existing questions/answers.)

Comment: Off-topic: you should load `hyperref` last (after `natbib`). Also drop the `pdftex` option.